# after updating OSMF.swf: Type was not found or was not compile-time constant: NetGroup and DimensionEvenet

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flash-builder, osmf

using Flash Builder 4 (and installed flashbuilder401-patch-mac).
want to use OSMF:

I removed OSMF.swf from project flex 4.1 libs and added osmf.swf v1.5 to libs 
I installed flashplayer_10_plugin_debug_ub-1

trying to build produces following problems:
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:DimensionEvent
and six lines of:
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:NetGroup
for all: Location is "Unknown" and Type is "Flex Problem"

code I'm trying to compile is simple MediaPlayerExample in osmf documentation

been reading through posts -- not sure what to try next

does someone have osmf working with Flash Builder 4 on MAC?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked (on MAC)
I removed old osmf.swc from:

Applications->Adobe Flash Builder 4->sdks >4.1.0->frameworks->libs  and replaced with the new 1.5 osmf.swc

Prior to that when using FlashBuilder two different (with different import paths in osmf package) would show up in code complete for AudioElement